# When I clone a team using Graph API how do I get the team ID from the response

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams

I am using the Graph API to create teams using the clone command.  Doing this successfully in Posh

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/myid/clone

according to MS I should see a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: /teams({id})/operations({opId})
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
```

but get nothing back, although the Team is created ok. I basically want the Team ID so I can then add my team owners.  At the moment I am having to do a

```
get-team | where {$_.displayname -eq $teamname} | Select-Object groupid
```

to get hold of the id so I can add owners.  I must be able to do this using Graph as well.

Does anyone know how to get the id from the clone response in graph?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on how to get the ID 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0#response

Basically the response is just a 200 - ok, but there is a header pointing to the process creating the team. Once that is finished it will return the ID of the team.

You could also implement a naive solution simply listing all the teams in your Org until you see it.